# Running CMD after ServiceFabric deployment to Node?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have an CLR profiler agent that I am adding to my ASP.NET application when I deploy to Service Fabric. I can successfully deploy my application and the components of my CRL agent to the server and I have also confirmed that my CLR profiler works if I RDP to the node and start it manually however; I can't for the life of my figure out how or where I can automate the running of this command after it has deployed to my node. I need to run a "startup.cmd" file once all the components of my application finish deploying.

The only place I can think of doing that is to modify the "Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1" that comes standard with my project. With Azure cloud there is a concept of a "ServiceDefinition.csdef" file which allows you launch tasks but not sure if this is available for Service Fabric?

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the best way to do it is. I assume you need the CLR Profiler to run all the time?

Its been a while since I used it, but the ServiceManifest.xml has an option for adding a SetupEntryPoint, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app for a detailed example on how to setup a guest exe as a service.

The gist is to add something like the following to the CodePackage tag in the servicemanifest:

```
<SetupEntryPoint>
     <ExeHost>
         <Program>profiler\ClrProfiler.exe</Program>
     </ExeHost>
</SetupEntryPoint>
```

As far as i recall the end result is that before each service startup, the profiler is run as well.

Note that if you have multiple instances of the same (under different names or some such) then the profiler will potentially be running multiple times on the same host/node.